# Should factory make context or concrete strategies objects in strategy-factory pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, c++, strategy, factory

In a typical strategy pattern

```
class Strategy
{
public:
    virtual int execute() const = 0;
}

class StrategyA : public Strategy
{
public:
    int execute() const override;
}

class StrategyB : public Strategy
{
public:
    int execute() const override;
}

class Context
{
public:
    Context() = delete;
    Context(Strategy* the_strategy);
    int execute() const;
private:
    Strategy* the_strategy_;
}
```

Should it be preferred to use a `Context` factory with the correct strategy injected

```
class ContextFactory
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Context> make(/*some parameters*/);
}

void ContextUser(/*some parameters*/)
{
    ContextFactory a_context_factory;
    auto a_context = a_context_factory.make(/*some parameters*/);
}
```

or a `Strategy` factory, leaving injection to the caller?

```
class StrategyFactory
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Strategy> make(/*some parameters*/);
}

void ContextUser(/*some parameters*/)
{
    StrategyFactory a_strategy_factory;
    Context a_context(a_strategy_factory.make(/*some parameters*/));
}
```

It seems to me the `Context` factory should be preferred as:

1. Less work for the caller.
2. Factory can manage lifetime of `Strategy` objects.
3. Facilitates design change; if the strategy pattern was latter changed to another design, say inheritance, the client code wouldn't change, only the factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind your factory to `Context`. Here's some disadvantages for your consideration.

1. More annoying to implement factories.
2. If you want to reuse the strategies for something other than `Context`, you have a problem.
3. If `Context` needs a second, independent strategy, you have a problem. With one factory responsible for creating the context, you now need N*M factories, one for each strategy combination.